# Start installation of a package, when the working one is finished

Tags: aptitude

Suppose I install a package on a debian based system via `sudo aptitude install mypackage`. Suppose the package is big and it takes long to download and install it.

When I notice that I want to install another package after invoking that command I have to wait until the first package is completely installed.

Is it possible to make aptitude to start automatically installing the second package, after the first one is finished?

Comment: Along with the good answer below, you could always write a basic script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list multiple packages to install at once:

```
aptitude install package1 package2
```

If you truly care about the order in which they are installed (you almost definitely don't, as aptitude takes into account dependencies and other subtleties automatically), or are looking for a more general solution, do something like the following:

```
aptitude install package1 && aptitude install package2
```

The logical AND (`&&`) operator will only perform the second command if the one preceding it succeeded (returned exit status 0).

If you are asking how to do this even *after* you initially did the command, try this another terminal:

```
aptitude-after() {
    printf '%s\n' "Waiting for current aptitude operations to finish"
    while pgrep -x aptitude >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        sleep 10
    done
    printf '%s\n' "Done, running new instance of aptitude."
    aptitude "$@"
}
```

Run it as `aptitude-after install mypackage2`. It will wait for all current instances of aptitude to finish.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. My problem is how to do it, when the install process of the first package is already running. Then I could wait until it is finished and start the installation of the second package. But is there a way to make aptitude install the package automatically after the first one is finished?

Comment: @student Ah, okay. I updated my answer.